# Changing values of column based on whether another column satisfy a criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subtract 1 from the values of column A if column B is <= 20.

```
A = c(1,2,3,4,5)
B = c(10,20,30,40,50)
df = data.frame(A,B)
```

output

```
  A  B
1 0 10
2 1 20
3 3 30
4 4 40
5 5 50
```

My data is very huge so I prefer not to use a loop. Is there any computationally efficient method in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
df$A[df$B <= 20]  <- df$A[df$B <= 20] - 1

#  A  B
#1 0 10
#2 1 20
#3 3 30
#4 4 40
#5 5 50
```

We can break this down step-by-step to understand how this works.

First we check which numbers in `B` is less than equal to 20 which gives us a logical vector

```
df$B <= 20
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Using that logical vector we can select the numbers in `A`

```
df$A[df$B <= 20]
#[1] 1 2
```

Subtract 1 from those numbers

```
df$A[df$B <= 20] - 1
#[1] 0 1
```

and replace these values for the same indices in `A`.

---

With `dplyr` we can also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(A = case_when(B <= 20 ~ A - 1, 
                       TRUE ~ A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
df$A <- ifelse(df$B < 21, df$A - 1, df$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[B <= 20, A := A - 1]
```